# How to prevent mysql implicit commit

Tags: mysql, transactions

The mysql [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/implicit-commit.html) states that certain statements will cause an implicit commit during a transaction.  For example:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (bar INT);
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (1);
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE mumble like foo;
ALTER TABLE mumble modify bar INT UNSIGNED;
ROLLBACK;
SELECT * FROM foo;
```

after the rollback, I get a single row back from foo -- the documentation actually says that an alter table shouldn't cause an implicit commit if you use the temporary keyword, but ALTER TEMPORARY TABLE is not valid syntax, and dropping a temporary table doesn't cause an implicit commit, so I suspect there's just a bug (at least as of 5.5.29)

In any case, what I'd like to do is to tell mysql to never implicitly commit, but instead to fail / rollback if a command is given which would cause an implicit commit.

I suspect there is no way to do this, having looked around a fair bit, but I'm hoping I'm wrong.   Hopefully someone on here knows :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another hacky approach that I just tried successfully is to get the create table DDL via the mysql specific command

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE `tableName`
```

Then make some regexp magic and craft a new DDL query that will create a temporary table based on the original table, with all the alter table changes incorporated into the create table.

In my PHP based project, I did the following to add a unique index to a temporary table. It did the trick and no more implicit commit occurred midst the transaction.

```
$createDDL = ... get from SHOW CREATE TABLE `tableName`
$nr = 0;
$createDDL = preg_replace("/CREATE TABLE `$tableName` \(/", "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `$tmpName` (\nUNIQUE `ukey-1` ($uniqCols),", $createDDL, -1, $nr);
if (!$nr)
  throw new Exception("CREATE TABLE replacement error. No reps made.");
mysqli_query($con, $createDDL);
```

**EDIT** By the way here are some bug (feature) reports (since many years). In the first you can see a response (dating to 2006) that states: since this behavior is the same as in oracle db, this is the consistent one...

- http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=22857
- http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=28109

Maybe a feature request "spamming campaign" should be initiated for this feature request to revive!

Comment: right, this is a workaround, I ended up doing something similar -- really hoping there'd be some kind of a way to do it -- but it appears from the bug reports they're not planning on fixing it either.  Thanks for finding those.

Answer (score 0):

At least with MySQL 5.5.19, you are right. The documentation claims `ALTER TEMPORARY TABLE` will not do an explicit commit, but MySQL chokes on the `TEMPORARY` keyword.

I can think of two possible workarounds:

**Workaround 1:**

Use a new temporary table in place of the `ALTER`:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (bar INT);
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (1);
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE mumble LIKE foo;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE mumble2 (bar INT UNSIGNED) SELECT * FROM mumble;
ROLLBACK;
SELECT * FROM foo;
```

The last statement produces the following output:

```
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Unfortunately, there is no way to rename `mumble2` back to `mumble`, as `RENAME` is not allowed for temporary tables, and `ALTER mumble2 RENAME mumble` commits implicitly.

**Workaround 2:**

Don't use temporary tables, but instead spawn a subprocess to run the commands that would cause the implicit commit:

Process 1:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (bar INT);
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (1);
```

Process 2 (and using a different connection to MySQL):

```
CREATE TABLE mumble LIKE foo;
ALTER TABLE mumble modify bar INT UNSIGNED;
```

Process 1:

```
ROLLBACK;
SELECT * FROM foo;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mumble;
```

Comment: the workarounds seem reasonable for my example case, but what I'm really looking for is a more general solution to the problem.  I don't think mysql should be implicitly committing during a transaction -- or if it's going to, there should be some way (safe mode / e.g.) to tell it to rollback and error out rather than doing that.

Comment: I agree. The docs suggest that MySQL should not implicitlly commit when executing *every* DDL statement involving `TEMPORARY` tables, so perhaps this has been fixed in a more recent version. Let's cross our fingers!

Comment: Unfortunately not fixed at 5.6.11, i am not sure if a bug is opened. And I haven't found a way to disable implicit commit...