# MySQL does commit of transaction when fails with creation of table

Tags: mysql, transactions, sql-insert, create-table

Server version: 5.7.17 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Here is my case.
I have two tables.

```
CREATE TABLE a (id INT PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE b (id INT PRIMARY KEY);
```

Now, I doing my transaction:

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO `a` VALUE (1);
CREATE TABLE b (id INT PRIMARY KEY);
```

Of course I expect that statement 3 (CRATE TABLE 'b') will fail since table already exists. And it does. The problem, that it does also insert as well, which should not before I run

```
COMMIT;
```

There is no way to rollback transaction - record '1' in table 'a' stays in place.

Do you have any ideas or thoughts how to avoid such behaviour? I've also noticed that when I intentionally do syntax error in CREATE TABLE STATEMENT it fails like expected, but record in 'a' isn't created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of statements that cause an implicit commit. CREATE TABLE is one of them.

More info:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/implicit-commit.html

Maybe [How to prevent mysql implicit commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16221993/how-to-prevent-mysql-implicit-commit) can help a bit.

Comment: Thank you for reference and explanation.

Do you know any way for locking DB during execution to keep consistency?

Comment: Added link to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16221993/how-to-prevent-mysql-implicit-commit might help.